# Display passed image in template, in VUE

Tags: image, function, vue.js, parameters, triggers

So I have this code:

```
    <template>
  <div id="search-wrapper">
    <div>
      <input
        id="search_input"
        ref="autocomplete"
        placeholder="Search"
        class="search-location"
        onfocus="value = ''"
        @keyup.enter.native="displayPic"
      >
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "vue-google-autocomplete";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      search_input: {},
      pic: {}
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.$refs.autocomplete

    );
    this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.photos) {
        place.photos.forEach(photo => {
          let pic=place.photos[0].getUrl()
          console.log(pic);
        });
      }
    });
  },
  methods: {
    displayPic(ref){
      this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.$refs.autocomplete);
      this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.photos) {
          place.photos.forEach(photo => {
            let pic=place.photos[0].getUrl()
            console.log(pic);
          });
        }
    })
  },
  }
}
```

I want to pass the "pic" parameter, resulted in displayPic, which is a function, into my template, after one of the locations is being selected.
I've tried several approaches, but I'm very new to Vue so it's a little bit tricky, at least until I'll understand how the components go.
Right now, the event is on enter, but I would like it to be triggered when a place is selected.
Any ideas how can I do that?
Right now, the most important thing is getting the pic value into my template.

Comment: what have you tried? from your code, i assume it's an URL to an image? if so `<img :src="pic" />` would do the trick

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work;

Comment: I even added  <img v-bind:src="'{{image}}'" > to the template, and updated the function like this:
displayPic: function(){
      this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.photos) {
          place.photos.forEach(photo => {
            this.pic=place.photos[0].getUrl()
            image=this.pic;
          });
        }
    })
  },
sorry for the indentation; I have no idea how to format it like code

Comment: remove the let and now it works..let is not visible in the template

Comment: its not only not visible in the template, its only visible within the scope of your `forEach` iterator function unless you use `this.pic`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <template>
      <div id="search-wrapper">
        <div>
          <input style="width:500px;"
            id="search_input"
            ref="autocomplete"
            placeholder="Search"
            class="search-location"
            onfocus="value = ''"
            v-on:keyup.enter="displayPic"
            @onclick="displayPic"
          >
          <img style="width:500px;;margin:5%;" :src="pic" >
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>

<script>
import VueGoogleAutocomplete from "vue-google-autocomplete";

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      search_input: {},
      pic:""
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    this.autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      this.$refs.autocomplete,
      {componentRestrictions: {country: "us"}}
    );

  },

  methods: {
    displayPic: function(){
      this.autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
      let place = this.autocomplete.getPlace();
      if (place.photos) {
          place.photos.forEach(photo => {
            this.pic=place.photos[0].getUrl()
          });
        }
    })
  },
  }
}
</script>
```